# function that contains " Mysql Insert into" command in vb6 clalled from a dll

Tags: mysql, dll, vb6, ado

I have made a function that adds record in a table:

```
Public Function AjouterCleint _ 
(ByVal pcode As String, ByVal prsoc As String, ByVal padresse As String, ByVal pcp As String) As Boolean


    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    MsgBox " code  " & "   : " & pcode & " / rsoc : " & prsoc & " / adresse : " & padresse & " /  cp : " & pcp
    AjouterCleint = False
    Dim rs As New Recordset
    Set rs = New Recordset
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    con.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" _
    & "SERVER=LOCALHOST;" _
    & " DATABASE=ste002;" _
    & "UID=root;PWD=; OPTION=3"
    con.Open
    Set rs = Nothing  
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient  
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Client (code,rsoc,adresse,cp) VALUES ('" _
    & pcode & "','" & prsoc & "','" & padresse & "','" & pcp & "')"
    MsgBox "5"
    rs.Open SQL, con, 3, 3
    MsgBox "6"
    Set rs = Nothing
    MsgBox "7"
    con.Close
    MsgBox "8"
    Set con = Nothing
    MsgBox "9"
    AjouterCleint = True
    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description & vbLf & Err.HelpContext & vbLf & Err.Source, , ""
 End Function
```

the value of parameters are not the some the I used. (I get in the message box:

```
 code: ????, rsoc: ????, adresse :???? , cp :1
```

When I use this function as the ordinary way(I add it in a module  and I call it as :

```
 a = AjouterCleint("13234", "1234", "1234", "1234")
```

it works, but when I put it in a dll , an error raised:

```
    2147217900
    [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 DRIVER] ... SYNTHAX error in “???????????????” in line 1.
    1000440
    Microsoft OLE DB providerfor ODBC drivers
```

the exception  is in this line:

```
    rs.Open SQL, con, 3, 3
```

I deleted all parameters in INSET COMMAND and I replaced

```
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Client (code,rsoc,adresse,cp) VALUES ('" _
    & pcode & "','" & prsoc & "','" & padresse & "','" & pcp & "')"
```

By

```
    SQL = "INSERT INTO Client (code,rsoc,adresse,cp) VALUES (12,12,12,12)"
```

And it works in the dll (I it called in other project and it works).
But I have to work with parameters.
So, any advices!!
Thanks a lot.
PS:” recordset.addnew”  don’t works also and an error was raised either.

this is how I call the functions in the dll:

```
Private Declare Function FunctionCalled Lib "C:\dlls\vbm2dll\Called.dll" _
(ByVal strValuePassed As String) As String

Private Declare Function AjouterCleint Lib "C:\dlls\vbm2dll\Called.dll" _
 (ByVal pcode As String, ByVal prsoc As String, ByVal padresse As String, ByVal pcp As String) As Boolean
Private Sub Form_load()

    txbValuePassed = "abc"

End Sub
Private Sub cmdCall_Click()
    txbValueReturned = FunctionCalled(txbValuePassed)
    a = AjouterCleint("1104", "1", "1", "1")
    MsgBox a & ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

it probably has to do with how you are passing the arguments to the DLL.  The code you show doesnt specify `ByRef` or `ByVal` so it is using the default, which I think was `ByRef` in VB6 but you probably arent passing the address.  This:

```
 Public Function AjouterCleint(ByVal pcode As String, _
                      ByVal prsoc As String, _
                      ByVal padresse As String, _
                      ByVal pcp As String) As Boolean
```

Might fix the problem.

EDIT

Your app code also needs to match that declaration to tell VB how to pass the vars:

```
 [Private|Public] Declare Function AjouterCleint Lib "MyLibName.dll" [Alias "AliasName"] _
         (ByVal pcode As String, _
          ByVal prsoc As String, _
          ByVal padresse As String, _
          ByVal pcp As String) As Boolean
```

Since a `BSTR` is basically still a pointer, you are likely going to have to copy the string data though it seems like it should work with both sides in VB):

```
Private Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" (ptrDst As Any, _
       ptrSrc As Any, ByVal lLen As Long)

 Private Function vbstr(ptr As Long) As String
    Dim l As Long

    l = lstrlenW(ptr)
    vbstr = String$(l, vbNullChar)

    Call RtlMoveMemory(ByVal StrPtr(vbstr), ByVal ptr, l * 2)

 End Function
```

Comment: you are right, there is a mistake in the dll description, the parameters values are: `???? ,??? ,???? , 1` . I don't know why. I will edit the post and show you the dll declaration

Comment: the declaration in your App is important - need to see that. The declaration and the one in the DLL create a sort of handshake...SEE EDIT

Comment: it *seems* right but I am rusty on my VB6.  I believe the strings are going to be passed as a pointer  and you will have to use the old VbPtrToStr trick of copying the data to a new string variable using `RtlMoveMemory`.  At which point, you have to question the value of putting this in a DLL.  I was thinking that could be avoided since both sides were VB6.    SEE EDIT